# How to make ROW_NUMBER work with duplicate records?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with transactional records that are duplicates. These are not bad duplicates, but they need to be assigned values to make them unique to the table. Being the use of the records is to look at them in order over time, I am using ROW_NUMBER to partition them by ID and ORDER BY Time.

Sometimes it works. Sometimes it fails.

**Example**

```
CASE WHEN [Record] = 'Start' 
     THEN 0 
ELSE -1 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [Date] DESC
END AS [RowNo]
```

**Expected Results**

```
ID,   Date,  RowNo
2002, 12:30, 1
2002, 12:29, 2
2002, 12:29, 3
2002, 12:29, 4
2002, 12:28, 5
3212, 01:10, 1
3212, 01:09, 2
3212, 01:08, 3
```

**Actual Results**

```
ID,   Date,  RowNo
2002, 12:30, 1
2002, 12:29, 2 <---Right
2002, 12:29, 2 <---Wrong
2002, 12:29, 3 <---Right
2002, 12:28, 4
3212, 01:10, 1
3212, 01:09, 2
3212, 01:08, 3
```

Is there a better approach to ensure accuracy?

Comment: Are you sure you use rownumber and not rank, dense rank? Rownumber begins with 1. You are not showing us actual statement...

Comment: Yes. That is my fault. I actually have a CASE statement with the original code that changes the first record from 1 to 0 based on another field not shown in the example.

Comment: Show actual code. Your current code should work...

Comment: Updated with clarity.

Comment: Still hard to tell what is going wrong. Can you give some data as well in order we can reproduce the behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ummm.  `ROW_NUMBER()` does work with duplicate records. (When there are duplicates, it's not deterministic which row will get which value.)

There is something else going on in your statement, something that's not shown.  A join operation, a GROUP BY, some additional filtering. We don't know what that is, but we know that `ROW_NUMBER()` does work with duplicates.

---

**EDIT**

This is suspicious:

```
CASE WHEN [Record] = 'Start' 
    THEN 0 
ELSE -1 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [Date] DESC
END AS [RowNo]
```

I've never seen an analytic function inside a `CASE` expression like that before. It looks to me like **`ROW_NUMBER()`** is only going to be evaluated in the context of the `ELSE`. (I'm not sure how SQL Server actually processes that.)

If I wanted `RowNo` to be 0, 1, 2, ... I would just subtract 1...

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [Date] DESC) - 1 AS RowNo
```

If there's a requirement to incorporate the condition on `[Record] = 'Start'` as part of the evaluation of `ROW_NUMBER`, then I'd include that in the `PARTITION`

```
  OVER(PARTITION BY [ID],CASE WHEN [Record]='Start' THEN 0 END ORDER BY ...)
```

If I needed to be manipulating the value returned by ROW_NUMBER(), I'd be finding a way to get that evaluated in the context of an inline view, or a CTE, to get that evaluated and returned, and *then* muck with the returned value in an outer query.

The point is that `ROW_NUMBER()` works fine with duplicates. If you're getting results you aren't expecting, it's because there's something else going on in the statement, like that CASE expression, or a join, or something.

Comment: I am using this off an UPDATE SELECT statement. It could be when the records are joining to a table, the duplicated record is being UPDATED and not the actual unique record with the correct ROW_COUNT. That's because I'm technically joining duplicates ontop of duplicates.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you could put a CASE in Over. Neat! But, I assume ROW_NUMBER is being applied in the ELSE statement on every record not matching the Case criteria. It works great. Like I said above, I think the issue is that I'm applying this to an UPDATE SELECT statement that is joining duplicates on duplicates. That means ROW_NUMBER is likely applying correctly, it's the JOIN that's sketchy because SQL does not know what duplicate to join. Hence the hit or miss.

Comment: Marking this one correct for helping me come to the correct answer by first explaining that ROW_NUMBER works with duplicates, by second helping me identify it's a problem in code I likely didn't think was the problem and finally, for teaching me something new.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get an unique identifier for each row is to use the %%Physloc%% (or %%lockres%% in SQL Server 2005) virtual column, that allows to identify the physical address of a row:

```
SELECT Id, Date, %%Physloc%%
FROM [your_table]
```

In this way you get better performances for huge tables than ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: I'll try it out. The table is large.